# Python: Why does my linear regression plot give me many messy coloured lines?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

This is the code I got, but I am unsure why it would even give me such a bad plot. Where did I went wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/housing.data', header = None, sep = '\s+')
df.columns = ["CRIM", "ZN", 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT','MEDV']
# print df
X = df.iloc[:,:-2].values
y = df.iloc[:,-1].values

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(X, lr.predict(X))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive. I don't want to run your code just to find out what is happening.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to plot? y vs y-predicted? If so, please try `plt.scatter(y, lr.predict(X))`

Comment: I'm trying to plot a X vs X-predicted, essentially a LR line that fits through the data but I'm not sure why the plot would connect all the data points together

Comment: X is a set of independent variables so X-predicted does not make sense. Instead, you use X to predict y.

Comment: Yes, I mean the original X as my independent variables in the X axis, while my y values would be the predicted values based on the independent variables from X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem/confusion here is with the dimensions of the problem.  My understanding is that you expect to see a line going through the points like [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) where the line function takes in X and outputs `lr.predict(X)`. You aren't going to see that one line because your X variable has 12 columns therefore you have **12 different independent variables**.

If you are trying to plot all of them along with your one dependent variable, `lr.predict(X)`, then you are going to need 13 dimensions.  The `plot` method isn't going to plot that for you. Instead it attempts to draw 12 different lines one for each dimension in X.  That's what you are seeing.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but I have only one column in the y variable of my test data. What am I doing wrong? My code doesn't have much difference compared to the one above. Is the predicted result an issue? Please help me out.